# Crystal Reports database connection not working

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

Recently a report that's existed for a while stopped working and it gave the error message:

> The viewer could not process the event. The database logon information
>   for this for this report is either incomplete or incorrect. [] ----
>   Error code:0 [CRWEB00000119]

The thing that's throwing me is that nothing about either the report or the database it's connected to changed and to "fix" it all I did was save a copy of the report and put in the same credentials and database settings. I tried the Verify Database option which is what a lot of the results said to do, and that said that the connection was fine, but it didn't fix the issue.

Most of the other instances I found usually happened when something was changed and Crystal got out of sync with the database for some reason.

Has anyone ever heard of or experienced this where Crystal just up and starts failing or have any idea of why this might have happened?

Comment: Did you upgrade/change the desktop client version?

Comment: Maybe, I'm checking now, but the odd thing is that all the other reports still worked fine. It was just two specific ones that failed.

Comment: @Sun Nope, no updates to the VM or UI.

Comment: Do you or someone else have access to the server? You can try to coordinate and monitory activity using ProcMon (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). You can try running it on the client side. It may help you troubleshoot why you're getting the error. The error message isn't helpful and doesn't point to something specific...